# Confidence interval for psychometric binomial GLM model on more than one subject in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, fixed-effects-model, glmm, psychometrics

I'm trying to estimate the confidence interval of a psychometric curve (binomial probit GLM), for a population (now only two subjects).

Suppose I've subject "a" and subject "b", which performs separately a task. The answers are recorded, and plotted against the stimulus level, giving us a sygmoidal curve.

Here is the data, and the code to plot the psychometric curve with its S.E.:

```
# data:
mydata <- structure(list(exp_dur = c(3250L, 2850L, 2250L, 2450L, 3450L, 
3450L, 3050L, 3450L, 2450L, 2650L, 3250L, 2650L, 2850L, 3250L, 
3050L, 2250L, 2450L, 2650L, 2250L, 2850L, 3050L, 2850L, 3050L, 
2850L, 2250L, 2450L, 3450L, 3250L, 3450L, 2850L, 3050L, 2250L, 
2450L, 3050L, 3450L, 2250L, 3050L, 3250L, 2450L, 2650L, 3250L, 
2650L, 2850L, 2450L, 2650L, 3450L, 2250L, 3250L, 2650L, 3250L, 
2450L, 2650L, 2650L, 3450L, 3450L, 3250L, 2450L, 2650L, 2850L, 
3050L, 3050L, 3250L, 2250L, 3050L, 3450L, 2250L, 2450L, 2850L, 
2850L, 2250L, 2250L, 3050L, 2650L, 2650L, 2450L, 3250L, 3050L, 
2850L, 2850L, 3250L, 3250L, 3050L, 2450L, 3050L, 2450L, 3450L, 
3250L, 2250L, 3450L, 2250L, 3450L, 2250L, 3450L, 2850L, 2650L, 
2450L, 2850L, 2650L), response_key_exp_resp = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("c", "l"), class = "factor"), lcorr = c(1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), subj = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("exp_dur", 
"response_key_exp_resp", "lcorr", "subj"), row.names = c(NA, 
98L), class = "data.frame")
```

For subject "a":

```
# subject a:
myfit.a <- glm(lcorr~exp_dur, binomial(probit), mydata, subset=subj=="a")
suba <- mydata[which(mydata$subj=="a"),]
sc1a <- with(suba, tapply(lcorr, exp_dur, mean))
plot(as.numeric(names(sc1a)), sc1a, log="x", xlab="Contrast", ylab="P correct", pch=21, cex=1.5)
cnt <- seq(2250, 3450, len=2000)
Long.Pred.a <- predict(myfit.a, newdata=data.frame(exp_dur=cnt), type="response", se.fit=T)
polygon(c(cnt, rev(cnt)), c(Long.Pred.a$fit + Long.Pred.a$se.fit, rev(Long.Pred.a$fit - Long.Pred.a$se.fit)), border="white", col="lightgrey")
lines(cnt, Long.Pred.a$fit, lwd=2)
points(as.numeric(names(sc1a)), sc1a, pch=21, cex=1.5)
```

[image: subject a]

For subject "b":

```
# subject b:
myfit.b <- glm(lcorr~exp_dur, binomial(probit), mydata, subset=subj=="b")
subb <- mydata[which(mydata$subj=="b"),]
sc1b <- with(subb, tapply(lcorr, exp_dur, mean))
plot(as.numeric(names(sc1b)), sc1b, log="x", xlab="Contrast", ylab="P correct", pch=19, cex=1.5)
cnt <- seq(2250, 3450, len=2000)
Long.Pred.b <- predict(myfit.b, newdata=data.frame(exp_dur=cnt), type="response", se.fit=T)
polygon(c(cnt, rev(cnt)), c(Long.Pred.b$fit + Long.Pred.b$se.fit, rev(Long.Pred.b$fit - Long.Pred.b$se.fit)), border="white", col="lightgrey")
lines(cnt, Long.Pred.b$fit, lwd=2, lty=2)
points(as.numeric(names(sc1b)), sc1b, pch=19, cex=1.5)
```

[image: subject b]

Now the psychometric curve of the group (subjects a and b) whith its plotted SE is:

```
# subject a+b
myfit.t <- glm(lcorr~exp_dur*subj, binomial(probit), mydata)
sc1t <- with(mydata, tapply(lcorr, exp_dur, mean))
plot(as.numeric(names(sc1t)), sc1t, log="x", xlab="Contrast", ylab="P correct", cex=1.5)
cnt <- seq(2250, 3450, len=2000)
Long.Pred.t <- predict(myfit.t, newdata=data.frame(exp_dur=cnt), type="response", se.fit=T)
polygon(c(cnt, rev(cnt)), c(Long.Pred.b$fit + Long.Pred.b$se.fit, rev(Long.Pred.b$fit - Long.Pred.b$se.fit)), border="white", col="lightgrey")
lines(cnt, Long.Pred.t$fit, lwd=2, lty=3)
points(as.numeric(names(sc1t)), sc1t, cex=1.5)
```

[image: subject a+b]

At a visual inspection, I don't think this is the confidence interval of the group. In fact, in the formula used, I did not specified that the data comes from 2 subject, and R interpret like this is a single subject.

So, what is the method to get the S.E. for the group in a GLM analysis?

I'm quite sure that the correct approach to this kind of problem is GLMM (`lme4` package), but I'm not familiar with it, and it seems to be hard to plot the predict data for `glmer` models, which would look like this:

```
mod1 <- glmer(lcorr ~ exp_dur + (1 + exp_dur|subj), family = binomial(link = "probit"), data=mydata)
```

How can I plot the S.E. of the group' psychometric curve?